# Foley Caress tiger

Tags: foley

Hey guys,

I'm stuck with this one. I have to Foley the sound of someone caressing a tiger. I've tried different things without any success. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 4):

Edit your post to let us know what you've already tried, that way we're not backtracking. I'm guessing that it's a relatively quiet, emotional scene. So the first things that come to mind are more about expressing the caress & less about the thought that there's a tiger in the room:

- Feather duster
- Stuffed animal
- Sweater
- Fur coat (or a Rycote windjammer)
- Throw pillows
- Bath robe

Basically things that have a softness to them with enough texture to make them sound a little interesting.

Comment: I used the duster. Haven't thougt about the rycote. Gread idea. Thanks
@ Steve, yeah that would be weird! I'll stick with the other options. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Steve. Thanks! It actually worked! Had a Rycote windjammer here in the studio and it sounds amazing! That's the sound that I was thinking about. 

Comment: Good to hear @Marco, I hope it cuts through the mix enough for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Scraping chest or legs  hair  with finger nails might do the trick

Comment: Thanks Filipe, I will. I also tried a dust cleaner, the one the old ladies use and it seems to be ok. Not sure yet though...

Comment: Actually, while I was sitting here literally scratching my head over this one, that sounded great too. Find someone with long enough hair and run your fingers through it. On second thought, have them do it. That could get weird in the foley pit.

Comment: @Steve - Hahaha!!! That would call for years of office taunts. Well, it would be with the colleagues I know. We all really dig in to each other... especially when it comes to being able to make mom jokes and have them audio related. I could see this one getting quite hairy. *Ba-Dum-Tisk!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good bird library, you might find some really wierd bird calls that you could use for that.  Don't forget the purring.

I'm pretty sure it was humming bird winds i was thinking of.

Comment: for a reference of an oversized purring cat, listen to Chris Watson's cheetah recording..

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd check out is if there is a music cue going there if you have the ability to coordinate with the sound super or the music scoring guys. It may be too low that it won't be heard in the first place.

Go pet a cat and see what it sounds like.

You don't necessarily hear the fur but you hear the person's foley and cloth. Make sure that is in there, too.

I'd try a rabbit's fur or other things made out of fur. Even try stroking your own hair (no offense if you don't have any).

Answer (score 1):

Just did something like this recently. Take the furry from a zepplin and put it against your chest to add some deep fleshy resonance and rub away. SImple really.

Answer (score 0):

Guys,

Thanks for your interest and for your help! I finally used the rycote windjammer and see if its aproved.

Best regards,
Marco